# Questions on iTextsharp

Tags: itext

How do I use iTextsharp library to modify objects in the PDF object stream.

Specifically, I wish to make use of the PDF manipulation features to insert/modify some form of watermark into the object stream that is not visible as displayed content.

Comment: *some form of watermark into the object stream that is not visible as displayed content* - please specify more clearly. The *watermark* shall not be visible, ok, but what shall it be?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I don't really know where to start, so I haven't really done anything yet. I've been using tools like pdfedit to explore the internals of PDFs.

Comment: @mkl I'm trying to see if I can place something in the object stream to uniquely identify this file. Following which, some sort of detection mechanism will be placed on my network to be able to track how it moves in the network. Somewhat similar to what network-based DLP solutions are doing.

Comment: Show the code you already have.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse there is no code, because I do not know how to use the library, was hoping for some guidance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why such a marker needs to be put into a content stream? Wouldn't it be easier if you defined your own entry in e.g. the **Catalog**?

Comment: @mkl that's a great idea, haven't really thought of that. What I'm trying to do is to explore different ways we can achieve this. For now I'm exploring what we can do in the object stream.